# What is the role of expo slug name?

Tags: react-native, async-await, push-notification, expo

I'm experiencing a really weird problem. I'm developing an expo application with react native, in expo managed workflow, and the issue is as follow:

I wanna execute the line: `await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);`. In development mode there was no problem at all, but when I published it to the store there was a bug, only in iOS. So I tested it on expo with "production mode".

When the user first launch the app, I wanna run the above command (in iOS). This line should open a dialog that asks for user permission to push notifications. This line is asynchronous (should be). If I'll run the following code:

```
console.log("1111")
await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
console.log("2222")
```

It should print 1111, then wait for user response, and then print 2222. The bug is that sometimes it doesn't do it. It just print 1111, and then print 2222, so the response of the user does not used. I can't get it in any way, because expo does not wait for the `askAsync` to return value, it just immeidatly return without user actual response. it just keep going to the next line and prints 2222. I tried to find the bug.

I opened a brand new app with expo, and just pasted the above code in my new app. The code suddenly worked as expected. So I realized there is something wrong in my code. I tried to move all the packages from the old project to the new one, still works. Then I moved the `app.json` file from the old project to the new project, and it won't work anymore. So I understood that the problem is in the `app.json` somehow. I isolated the problem, and found that it is about the `slug` in the `app.json` file. When I change the slug, the problem sometimes happens, and sometimes not. For example, if I put in the `slug` the value `learnmath` the problem will happen, and if I change the `slug` value to `client111` the problem will not happen, and the above code will work as expected.

***What is the role of slug in expo app.json file? I can't figure it out!***

How is the slug even connected to any of this?

**This problem only happens in iOS.**

Answer (score 3):

so the reason it's working on a brand new app is because you have not asked the operating system for that permission before. You cannot ask for the same permission more than once in your app (that could be pretty annoying to users).

Once a user grants permission, subsequent calls will return "granted", even though it doesn't prompt the user every time.

As for the slug- this is used to differentiate different "apps" in the Expo client. So the Expo client app had stored that you had granted notification permission for **learnmath**, so when you changed that to **client111**, the Expo client thought- "oh, this must be a new project, which we haven't obtained permission for yet"

[See here for more info](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/#manually-testing-permissions)

Comment: Thank you for the comment!
I do know that in iOS I can ask for the permission only once, but in my case I reinstalled the app every time I tested it, so it should be considered as a new app. 
I tested it many times, and every time I reinstalled the Expo client app. It still never worked for "learnmath", and for "client" it always working. How could that be?

Comment: Could you try this on a simulator, after clearing it completely with `Device` > `Erase All Contents and Settings...`

Comment: I tested it on a brand new phone that never had expo. It happend. I already found this forum:
https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-29-0-on-ios-is-no-longer-resolving-permissions-askasync-promise-for-notifications/12044/14
Could it still be the problem?

Comment: Solved it. Downgraded from expo 40 to expo 39, and problem solved. here is probably bug in expo 40

Comment: I just encountered the problem on expo sdk 41, when I change the slug the app works, once I use the original app slug it won't work, I wonder why that is.